# Code Blocks: not loading images when launched out of compiler

Tags: c++, image, loading, codeblocks, sfml

I made an application in code blocks that loads images. These images are in folder, placed in root directory of the .cbp file. When I compile & run the application, the images load without a problem. However, when I launch the application from the debug folder (where app is created), the images aren't loaded. Am I doing it the right way? I mean, isn't there a button to finalise an application that would prevent this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the Debug Folder is in the same directory as your cbp file, and the executable is in the Debug folder, do: "../Folder/pic" You see, ".." basically means "look one directory up"

Edit: Alternatively, you could copy the folder with your images to the Debug Folder too. Then it would be in the so called "working directory" of the application again.